# How to use Google Play Games saved games (snapshots), offline?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-play-games

From the official guide:

> Offline support
>
> Your game can still read and write to a saved game when the player's
>   device is offline, but will not be able to sync with Google Play games
>   services until network connectivity is established. Once reconnected,
>   Google Play games services asynchronously updates the saved game data
>   on Google's servers.

I'm currently using the included view to show actual save games. Everything works as expected if i can login the client, but turning off the network results in failed client login at startup and consequent fail creating the intent. I don't think it's relevant but i'm using Xamarin wrapper to GMS (60.1142.1).

Do i have to skip using the integrated view and work with "known name" snapshots? Is there a way to offline login to GMS / Google Play Services?

```
private void showSavedGamesUI(bool forSave)
{
    try
    {
        int maxNumberOfSavedGamesToShow = 4;

        if (mGoogleClient == null)
            mGoogleClient = BaseGameActivity.mHelper.getApiClient();

        var intent = SnapshotsClient.GetSelectSnapshotIntent(mGoogleClient,
            "My Saves", forSave, forSave, maxNumberOfSavedGamesToShow); //<-- Exception if client not connected
        if (forSave)
            Game1.Activity.AddActivityResultHandler(RC_SAVED_GAMES, onSaveGameSelected);
        else
            Game1.Activity.AddActivityResultHandler(RC_SAVED_GAMES, onLoadGameSelected);
        Game1.Activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, RC_SAVED_GAMES);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        cancelled();
    }
}
```

Comment: Login the client require the internet, to keep the status, try to detect if the internet is available. You could do this using Essentials.Connectivity part, such as `if (current == Connectivity.NetworkAccess.Internet){}`. Check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android#using-connectivity

Comment: So essentially i can use the saves "provided at startup i was online" ?